# My site doesn't show correctly in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

my site: http://www.healthot.com doesn't show correctly in iPhone and other mobiles. It's scales the window, so it's necessary to zoom out for see the page. Check this photo and you are going to understand all: http://www.dropbox.com/s/27o9ubygfl4ci3w/Foto%2016-04-14%2018%2058%2005.png

What can i do?

Comment: You can look into creating and serving a mobile only version of your site or responsive design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your view port meta tag from:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

To:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Learn more on how [viewport works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).